# Select all rows that are not assigned to a group (in another table)

Tags: mysql, sql

**Information**

I have two tables. `accounts` & `accounts_groups_assigned`

`accounts` has all account information, and `accounts_groups_assigned` contains ids of the accounts that have been assigned to a group. The main structure isnt anything unique. Just basic ID columns and names etc, if it is really needed I will add it to the post but as previously mentioned, its pretty generic.

**Problem**

I need to be able to select all the accounts from `accounts` that have not been assigned to a group yet. Now this is fairly easy to do in PHP but I would like to be able to do it with one query using MySQL.

As requested, table structures.

`accounts`

`ID | Name`

And

`accounts_groups_assigned`

`ID | Group_id | account_id`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I do not know where to even begin with checking another table inside of a query, I have tried researching left joins and sub query's but I'm unsure on what I should aim to get back from the sub-query that would be useful for the initial query. Lastly, thank you for editing your comment to something I could actually reply to.

Comment: At the least, we need to see the table structures.

Comment: Updated with table structures, hope they help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM accounts a
   LEFT JOIN accounts_groups_assigned aga ON a.ID = aga.account_id
WHERE aga.account_id IS NULL
```

The `LEFT JOIN` here links the two tables together, ensuring all records from `accounts` will be shown, even if they have no matching rows in the `accounts_groups_assigned` table. In case of a no match, the `account_id` in `accounts_groups_assigned` will be `NULL`.

We then can use the `WHERE aga.accounts_groups_assigned IS NULL` to find all cases where an `account_id` has not yet been linked to a `group_id`.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you for making an effort to solve the question rather than nit-picking my question for free edit points.

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    accounts 
LEFT JOIN accounts_groups_assigned groups ON accounts.id = groups.account_id 
WHERE 
    groups.account_id IS NULL;
```

`LEFT JOIN` links the table on matching `id` fields. The `WHERE` clause gives you your desired results by selecting all `accounts` where there isn't a `accounts_groups_assigned`...assigned. See [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) article for a detailed explanation on `JOINS`.

Comment: I'd expect this to work too! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I like using a NOT IN for excluding data from another table as it is much clearer what's actually going on than doing LEFT JOIN and checking for NULL.

```
SELECT 
    columns
FROM 
    accounts a
WHERE 
    a.id NOT IN (
    SELECT 
        account_id
    FROM 
        accounts_groups_assigned
)
```

Comment: This works too but `JOINS` are usually faster than sub-queries. The best way to go about it would be to run both with `Show Execution Plan` and compare. But it's rare for a sub-query to be faster.